# Argument cannot be null when testing controller that displays some dates on a lightning page

Tags: apex, controller, aggregateresult

Controller:

```apex
public with sharing class DatesController {
    
    public String vehicleId {get;set;}
    public List<AggregateResult> AggregateResultList{get;set;}
    public List<AggregateResult> AggregateResultList2{get;set;}
    
    public DatesController() {
        
        vehicleId = ' ';
        
        this.vehicleId=System.currentPageReference().getParameters().get('id');
        
        System.debug('...................vehicleId=='+vehicleId);
        
        Id i= Id.valueOf(vehicleId);
        
        System.debug('...................Id=='+i);
        
        AggregateResultList = new List<AggregateResult>();
        AggregateResultList = [
            SELECT
                FORMAT(MIN(Date1__c)) Date1,
                FORMAT(MIN(Date2__c)) Date2,
                FORMAT(MIN(Date3__c)) Date3
            FROM Object1
            WHERE Id = :i
            GROUP BY Id
        ];
        
        System.Debug(AggregateResultList.size());
        
        AggregateResultList2 = new List<AggregateResult>();
        AggregateResultList2 = [
            SELECT
                FORMAT(MIN(Date4__c)) Date4
            FROM Object2
            WHERE Lookup__c = :i
            GROUP BY Lookup__c]
            ;
        System.Debug(AggregateResultList2.size());
    }
}
```

Test class I am trying to use:

```apex
@isTest
public class DatesControllerTest {
    
    public static testMethod void testMyController(){
        
        Object1 stu = new SPOrders__c();
        stu.Name='Wes';
        stu.Date1__c=Date.today();
        insert stu;
        
        Object2 vehicle = new VIN__c();
        vehicle.Name='TestVehicle';
        insert vehicle;
        
        SPOrders__c c = [select id,name from Object1 WHERE Name = 'Wes' limit 1];
                
        PageReference pageRef = Page.FPTest;
        Test.setCurrentPage(pageRef); 
        
        DatesController controller = new DatesController();
        controller.VehicleId = c.Id;
        
        ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('VehicleId', c.id);              
    }
}
```

My understanding is that the `vehicleId` is not getting appended to the vfp for testing and that is the null argument? I have spent countless hours trying to solve. I appreciate any direction/assistance provided. I am new to apex/vfp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These lines are in the wrong order:

```
SP2DatesController controller = new DatesController();
controller.VehicleId = c.Id;

ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('VinId', c.id);
```

Your `SP2DatesController` constructor attempts to access the `id` parameter (note, you've incorrectly put `VinId` in your test class), but you don't populate the parameter value until *after* you initialize `controller`, which invokes the constructor.

Move the third line first and fix the parameter name.

Comment: Resolved. Thanks for the quick assistance. That fixed the errors.